# How to display the checkbox label with link through label property in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to display the react bootstrap checkbox label with link through label property?

```
<Form.Check className='checkbox-custom'                   
                  label="I agree to the {<a href={url}>terms and conditions</a>}"
                  name="group1"
                   type={type}
                  id={`inline-${type}-1`}
                />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can for example wrap the label with a span:

```
<Form.Check
    type="checkbox"
    label={
        <span>
            I agree to the
            <a href={url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                terms and conditions
            </a>
        </span>
    }
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-blackwell-ftmn75